# C++ getline(cin, str) giving me extra line

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in c++. I am using Cygwin and eclipse in window 7 and I am trying to write a program to just ask user to input a string and just print it out. I have the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string mystr;
    cout << "What's your name? ";
    getline (cin, mystr, '\n');
    cout << "Hello " << mystr << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I also try:

```
getline(cin, mystr);
```

They both gave me a out put like below.

output:

```
What's your name? nick
Hello nick
.
```

Why is the full stop goes to the next line?
Can someone tell what happen and teach me how to fix it.

Comment: I just tried this myself and I got the output `Hello nick.` followed by a newline if use `getline (cin, mystr, '\n');` I am using gcc 4.7

Comment: Perhaps cygwin isn't properly doing line-ending conversions.

Comment: should I use MinGW instead?

Answer (score 0):

In gcc 4.6.3

```
getline (cin, mystr);
```

and

```
getline (cin, mystr, '\n');
```

both are printing the string as you are expecting.

Comment: you can use a dummy getchar() to avoid this behavior in your compiler.

Comment: after the getline() function write a getchar() and see if it helps.

Comment: it said getchar() is not declare in this scope

Comment: I added #include <stdio.h> to make it compile, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I have seen getline(), gets() etc creating trouble most of the times in Dev, Cygwin etc. By the way, why don't you try just `cin>>mystr` instead of getline().

Comment: I am trying to ask user to input a sentence, so i have to use getline

Comment: should I use MinGW instead?

Comment: I uninstall Cygwin and use MinGW instead, and it works now. thanks

Comment: :D told ya! these compilers like Dev, Cygwin create trouble at times. Good Luck!